# ASP.NET Forms Authentication using third party javascript library

Tags: jquery, wcf, json, asp.net-membership, mootools

I have a website where I currently use ASP.NET's built in Authentication, profile and role management. I would like to move some functionality (including authentication) to the client side using a third party javascript library like JQuery or Mootools without the use of ScriptManager and generated proxy classes.

There is very limited information on this topic but I managed to find this [article](http://ajax.sys-con.com/node/581103) which creates a WCF authentication end point to use with a SilverLight application. I can't find any information on how to use a WCF authentication end point with a third party javascript library and JSON.

If you have any links or information, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're probably struggling with finding resources for this because putting your authentication control on the client side is just not safe.

What are your reasons for wanting to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you reply.

You are probably right but I see this functionality on a lot of websites. I basically allows you to sing in to your account from any page without navigating away from it.

I found an [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2008/e-12/09/working-with-thasp-net-ajax-authentication-service.aspx) on how to accomplish this by adding a scriptmanager server tag in the code. However, I want to stay away from any automatically generated proxy classes if possible and accomplish this using JSON.